# Confusion on creating index to improve join performance in mysql

Tags: mysql

I read many posts on forum, but still I have confusion on creating index to speed up join queries in mysql, here is my doubt

I have two tables, one is `category` table which just contains few thousand lines, and contains all information about data, and another one is `geo_data` table which contains huge amount of data, I join `geo_data` table based on 2 keys `s_key1` and `s_key2`. Following is structure of table

**category** table

```
CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `s_key1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `s_key2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STD_DATE` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `LATITUDE` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `LONGITUDE` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `COUNTRY_CD` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INSTR_CODE` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CANADACR_CD` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PROBST_T` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TYPE` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=32350 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**geo_data** table

```
CREATE TABLE `geo_data` (
  `s_key1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `s_key2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MAGNETIC` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `GRAVITY` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `BATHY` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `CORE` float DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I have many  tables like `geo_data` table which contains `s_key1`, `s_key2` and other columns, in my application I often use fields std_date,latitude,longitude,country_cd,type from `category` table

I do inner join, sometimes left join depending on the requirement, for example my query looks like below

```
SELECT 
        c.s_key1,
        c.s_key2,
        c.std_date,
        c.latitude,
        c.longitude,
        g.magnetic,
        g.bathy 
FROM 
        category c, geo_data g 
WHERE 
        c.s_key1 = g.s_key1 && c.s_key2 = g.s_key2;
```

and sometimes my `where` clause will have something like this too

```
WHERE 
            c.latitude between -30 to 30 AND
            c.longitude between 10 to 140  AND
            c.country_cd = 'INDIA' AND
            c.type = 'NON_PROFIT';
```

So what's the right way of creating index to speed up my query, whether below one right ? please someone help

```
create index `myindex` on 
`category` (s_key1,s_key2,std_date,latitude,longitude,country_cd)

create index `myindex` on 
`geo_data` (s_key1,s_key2)
```

and One more doubt whether both tables (category,geo_data) should have index key to speed up performance or only geo_data table  ?

Comment: with the join query I 'd go for create index `myindex` on 
`geo_data` (s_key1,s_key2) due to the fact you have an && in where statement

Comment: @YehiaAwad : sometimes I need to compare latitude, longitude as well from category table, so if I create index using only s_key1,s_skey2 on category table will it improve performance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the where condition it makes sense to simplify the first index as:

```
create index `myindex` on 
 `category` (s_key1,s_key2)
```

The original however can improve the performance in terms that it doesn't have to access the full table row to get the other values. However it makes the index bigger and therefore slower. So it depends on whether this is optimization for only this query or there are more of them which use only the s_key1 and s_key2 (or with combination with other columns).

Regarding the clarification - for lat/lng check it will make sense to move  std_date after lat/lng (or remove completely):

```
create index `myindex` on 
`category` (s_key1,s_key2,latitude,longitude,std_date,country_cd)
```

Comment: sometimes I need to compare latitude, longitude as well from category table, so if I create index using only s_key1,s_skey2 on category table will it improve performance ?

Comment: So far geo_data table only s_key1, and s_key2 are enough right ?